# automatically format row/columns vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing this code and I encounter difficulties to format automatically rows and columns. The problem is at the AUTOFIT comment below. I want to format the first row (headers) and then the entire table automatically. I am able to do it by the range function (typing the exact range of the cells), but i would like to do automatically as I did for the copy paste in the middle of the code. In particular I would like to format the first row in blue and the entire table in white with continuous borders.

I tried many different commands but everytimes it gives me an error. Some clue?

```
   Option Explicit
    Public wkbk As Workbook
    Public mybook As Workbook

    Sub Opentrading()

    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim Path As String
    Dim nyear As String
    Dim nmont As String
    Dim nday As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long

    Dim StartCell As Range
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    FolderPath = "filename"
    nyear = Sheet6.Range("J3")
    nmont = Sheet6.Range("J5")
    nday = Sheet6.Range("J7")
    Path = FolderPath & "\" & nyear & "-" & nmont & "-" & nday &  Southern_Europe" & ".xlsx"
    Set mybook = ThisWorkbook
    mybook.Worksheets("Data").UsedRange.ClearContents
    mybook.Worksheets("Data").Cells.ClearFormats
    Set wkbk = Workbooks.Open(Path)
    Set sht = wkbk.Sheets("Southern_Europe")

    'Find Last Row and Column
    Set StartCell = sht.Range("D1")
      LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
      LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Copy paste
     wkbk.Worksheets("Southern_Europe").Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn - 5)).Copy mybook.Worksheets("Data").Range("A1")

    'Autofit
     With mybook.Worksheets("Data")
                .UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
                .Range("A1:S1").Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    '            .Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn - 5)).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous
    '            .Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn - 5)).Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlContinuous
        End With

      wkbk.Close
    End Sub
```

Comment: So is the explicit question: How do I format the first row in blue and the entire table in white with continuous borders? First row of table? Blue background?

Comment: Is the typo in the line `Path = FolderPath...` accidental or is it also apparent in your code? (Note it should be `... & nday &  Southern_Europe & ".xlsx"`

Comment: @BruceWayne is just a typo!

Comment: @QHarr exactly! the color is not important, blue white or black, i can modify it later. The important thing is the syntax